# svn checkout on windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed svn console client from these binaries - http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows - 1.5.6, 1.6.4, 1.6.5. But no release seems to work. Just it can't checkout from any repo (code.gjangoproject.com; code.google.com):

> svn couldn't connect to server.

There is a bug on debian - http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=531338 with the same description.

**How to solve this bug on windows?**

Platform: windows-xp-sp3.
SVN-client: 1.5.6, 1.6.4, 1.6.5

**UPDATE:**
I don't want to host the svn server on WinXP, my aim is to be able to checkout from svn servers.

**UPDATE2:**
Just installed tortoiseSVN and found the old proxy setting. Seems tortoiseSVN saves its settings to registry and doesn't remove them after deinstallation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using an other SVN client ?
Head to http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Comment: the same problem. couldn't connect to server -(

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't connect to the server, then even the *svn list* command won't work.  In that case I'd try one more tactic.  From your command line, try `telnet <yoursvnserver> 3690`.  If you get an error with that, it just might be more descriptive than "can't connect".

Answer (score 0):

Make life really, really easy on yourself and just install [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). Fastest, easiest, free-est way of getting SVN running on Windows.